# Retrieve ember data relationship with one API call

Tags: javascript, rest, ember.js, ember-data

I've two models:

ticket:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({

  name: DS.attr('string'),
  email: DS.attr('string'),

  messages: DS.hasMany('message'),

})
```

messages:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({


  message: DS.attr('string'),

  date: DS.attr('date'),

  ticket: DS.belongsTo('ticket', { async: true }),

});
```

And a router with this model method:

```
  model(params) {
   return this.get('store').findRecord('ticket', params.id,  {reload: true, include: 'messages'});

 },
```

At the page reload all ok, only a call to `tickets/:id` is made but sometimes ember make a bunch of calls to `messages/:id`. Why don't use the included data and try to retrieve from the server?

I've tried `async: false` on hasMany relation but I've this error:

`` Error: Assertion Failed: You looked up the 'messages' relationship on a 'ticket' with id 15 but some of the associated records were not loaded. Either make sure they are all loaded together with the parent record, or specify that the relationship is async (`DS.hasMany({ async: true })`) ``

Any idea?

This is the GET `tickets/:id` response:

```
{"data":
{
"id":"15",
"type":"tickets",
"attributes":{...},

"relationships":{"messages":{"data":[{"id":"1478482584658","type":"messages"},{"id":"1478482588516","type":"messages"},{"id":"1478517720","type":"messages"},{"id":"1478517813","type":"messages"},{"id":"1478517893","type":"messages"},{"id":"1478530030","type":"messages"},{"id":"1478530032","type":"messages"},{"id":"1478533446","type":"messages"}]}}},

"included":[

{"id":"1478482584658","type":"messages","attributes":{...}},{"id":"1478482588516","type":"messages","attributes":{...}},
...
}
}
]
}
```

Why don't take data from `included` and make other calls to the server?

Answer (score 0):

What about promise?

> While working with relationships it is important to remember that they return promises.
>   https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.1.0/models/working-with-relationships/#toc_relationships-as-promises